# Team foundation server query that sorts through math?

Tags: tfs

I recently started using TFS (Team Foundation Server), and I am now encountering some problems constructing my desired queries.

I would like a query that can take all work-items, divide their business value with their effort, and sort by the result of that calculation.

Is this possible? Does TFS support basic math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS has a Cube which can be used within Excel, if you open excel select the Data Tab, select "From Other Sources", then select from Analysis Services, you should be able to see a list of Build and Work item entities, you should be able to create a pivot table to work out your calcs.

This link may help  you [Tech Ed Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV311)

Cheers

Comment: Any other solutions than that?

Comment: I think you can customise your work items, and use calculated fields, but I have not played around with it, but just a word of warning, custom work items, dont always upgade.